# Python calling function defined in __init__.py not working

Tags: python, module, init

I created sub folder `module1` with just _`_init__.py`

```
def print_hello():
    print('Hello')

__all__ = ["print_hello"]

print('Init loaded')
```

inside `main.py` i have

```
import module1

print_hello()
```

Output as follows

```
print_hello()
^^^^^^^^^^^
NameError: name 'print_hello' is not defined
Init loaded
```

Comment: `include` is not valid python.  This cannot be your real code.  Please post your real code.

Comment: @JohnGordon Check above had a typo.

Comment: `__all__` affects what importing `*` does: replace `import module1` by `from module1 import *`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does \_\_all\_\_ mean in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834/what-does-all-mean-in-python)

Comment: @PM77-1 And that file is `module1/__init__.py`, which defines a module which might also be a package (if there are other `.py` files in the same directory).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Importing a module does not automatically bring all of its variables and functions into the current namespace (unless you use `import *`).

You still have to refer to the specific variable or function you want to use.

```
import module1
module1.print_hello()
```

or

```
from module1 import print_hello
print_hello()
```

or

```
from module1 import *
print_hello()
```